# ViewBag is NULL after RedirectToAction (+ reinitialization of ViewBag)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have RedirectToAction as a return value in a controller and in my view I use ViewBag. While it's a well-known problem that ViewBag becomes empty after a RedirectToAction.  I have a problem when I reinitialize ViewBag values in my overloaded controller in the OnActionExecuting method. ViewBag is empty again.
But the problem is that on my local PC (win7) it's working okay but on the web-hosting server (win 2008) it crashes. So can some one help saying what can cause that? Maybe it's a setting or something?

Comment: Post your code so we can understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an exception deep inside data layer which was incorrectly captured and thereby prevented from propagation but caused ViewBag vanishing.

So be careful with exceptions catching.

Answer (score 46):

The ViewBag and ViewData only survives the current request. TempData is the thing to use when you use redirects (and only then): http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications states this clearly:

> [...] the TempData object works well in one basic scenario:
>
> - Passing data between the current and next HTTP requests

Comment: TempData uses session, and I don't want to use Session, also query string neither, how can pass value after redirection ?

Comment: You can always override the TempData provider, if you want to. Here is an example of a cookie-based TempData provider, but you can always create something else that makes sense to you in your scenario: https://brockallen.com/2012/06/11/cookie-based-tempdata-provider/

Comment: thanks for quick reply for old post. After redirection, response object renews and cookie property can not hold the value.

Comment: You need to work out what works best in your scenario. Of course cookie is re-sent on a ridirect, I don't know your exact problem.

Comment: Ok, I don't use session in my project, session is disabled on the system. There is a basket on the site, you can add items to the basket whether you logged in or not. but if you are logged in and if you wanna log out, after redirection, I need to empty your basket. 
So, let's say you have something in your basket, and you wanted to logout. I have to log you out then I have redirect you to homepage, also I need to empty local storage based basket. Now I solve this issue with querystring but, I am looking the alternative solution.